# mysql general log can't find file

Tags: mysql

I am using ubuntu and I gave the file im using mysql.log a chmod of 777. I also tried using chown mysql:mysql and here is the segment in my my.cnf file.

```
general_log_file        = /var/www/logs/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
```

I ran a simple query and nothing happen in the file. So I went into mysql via terminal and typed

```
SET GLOBAL general_log:=1;
```

and I get

```
ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/var/www/logs/mysql.log' not found (Errcode: 13)
```

The file does exist, I don't understand why mysql can't see it. I tried these commands to see if the data was saved into mysql and the information looks correct

```
SELECT @@global.general_log;
SELECT @@global.general_log_file;
SELECT @@global.log_output;
```

What chown user do I need to use? I have tried everything and mysql just doesn't want to log queries. I want to log all queries. This is a development server so it's not live.

Answer (score 1):

Mine are set in a custom location with the permissions `-rw-rw-rw-` and owner and group are set to `root`. You should also make sure that whatever user you're giving the permissions to has access to every directory above the one you're trying to give it access to.

Also, I'd recommend that you don't put your logs inside of `public_html`. This will allow malicious persons to gain information about your SQL version and such, and even worse, give them a place to see if what they're trying is working.

Comment: thanks i'll try this when i get on my machine. My sites are located in /var/www/vhosts where logs are outside of the public.

Answer (score 1):

> If you specify no name for the general query log file, the default
>   name is host_name.log. The server creates the file in the data
>   directory unless an absolute path name is given to specify a different
>   directory.

For example in mysq server, the file is:
**/var/lib/mysql/myServer.log**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html